# Why dynamic type methods are not visible?

Tags: java

Lets say that we have:

```
interface A{
    void foo();
}

class B implements A{
    void foo(){}
    void doNothing(){}
}
```

I create a B instance

```
 A object=new B();
```

Why at object.doNothing() call is a compile error raised?

Comment: Plus one; fair question. The language is designed that way so you get the benefits (e.g. program stability) of compile-time type checking. Other languages (e.g. VBA) are much more lapse than this. If you *know* or even *suspect* that `object` is a `B` then you can attempt a cast, after which you can access `doNothing`.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in compile time, Compilter check for reference type method binding. So the method `doNothing()` is not available in the interface `A`

At compile time the compiler can't be sure if the call to the method `doNothing()` on these references actually refer to which version of the method - the super class version or the sub class version.

Answer (score 1):

Because object is A and A has no method named doNothing. If you wanted to do the doNothing method, either add it to interface A:

```
interface A {
    void foo();
    void doNothing();
}
```

or create object as B not A.

```
B object = new B();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using *"polymorphism"*. This is the technique when you use an object as its parent.
Assume this implementation:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void go();
}

class Dog implements Animal {
    public void go() {
        walk();
    }
}
class Fish implements Animal {
    public void go() {
        swim();
    }
}
class Duck implements Animal {
    public void go() {
        fly();
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
Animal[] animals = {new Dog(), new Fish(), new Duck()};
```

Now whenever you want an animal to go, you can simply call the `go();` method of the preferred array element as an animal (without any worry about their type of movement)


By now, can you **ask a fish to walk**? No. Because not all animals know walking.

This is why you can't call the child's method, on parent object, because the **parent sees its children same** and it just knows about *going* not *walking, etc.*

In your question, `A` interface just knows about `void foo();` method and has no idea about `void doNothing();` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because the type `A` has no `#doNothing` method, and the variable `object` has the compile time type `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `object` is `A` and in `class A` you dont have any function named `doNothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sees `object` with the external interface of `A` and as `A` has no method `doNothing` a compile error arises.